# Are there cultures who swear oaths of servitude for saving of a life?

Tags: sociology

In the book *Robinson Crusoe* (and to a lesser extent the movie *Robin Hood: Prince of Thieves*), there is a character who, when his life is saved by the protagonist, swears allegiance (and, basically, servitude) until death or the favor is returned. It is implied that this is something which is a part of the culture of the person who's life is saved.

While I am aware that such things are possible, they most certainly were not a part of Native American culture, but I was curious if any such culture exists or existed past?

Comment: I think you should also consider that Robinson Crusoe was written in the early 18th century, a time when having a native as your slave was considered in the normal order of things...

Comment: @nico I know. And that type of thought is common for literature of that time (Count de Monte Christo comes to mind too), but I was wondering if such a culture did exist at all.

Comment: I replaced the word ["slavery"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slavery) with the word ["servitude"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/servitude) as the first implies that a slave is as such by force, whereas the second doesn't imply that.

Comment: Sounds off-topic to me - asking if something exists? Is there anyone making a specific *claim* that it exists? (Someone non-fictional).

Comment: I added a condition that would permit an answer that included a historical account of such a culture.  I would suspect any culture that did exist like that in the 1700's most likely has changed in the last 300+ years.

Comment: @JohnC I've seen examples of this occur frequently in various literature/media. I think it is common enough that asking if there is a real world basis is on topic.